# Nivo Video Slider in Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I am trying to implement a video slider using nivo plugin. But I have a problem when I am trying to display it in my production site, no results are being displayed.

I'm working with views, and panel fields. When I run the query using the live preview, I am getting the desired results, but when I try to see it in my production site, nothing happens.

How can I implement a video slideshow using the nivo slider plugin?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache?

Comment: Yes, like 10 times, lol. But stills not showing the results.

Comment: Then I have no idea of what could be wrong. Are you sure you saved the view? (updating a field will update the live preview but not the view)

Comment: Yes i do save the view. And then i cleared the cache, but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

If its working in your live preview but not on the production site, the culprit I can think of is `contextual filters`.

On the page where you have the final display check if the contextual filters are being passed correctly. Enable `devel module` and check the query that is being executed on the page. That will give you a better idea.